# How to rename a file using Perl

Tags: perl, file-rename

I have been trying to rename a file for the past hour using perl. I have researched forever and have tried everything yet nothing worked. How can I rename a file using perl? Here is my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use File::Copy qw(move);


# Open the log file
    my $log_file = 'testLog.log';
    open my $log_fh, '<', $log_file or die "Could not open file $log_file: 
$! +";

# Create New File
    my $new_log_file = 'testLog.log';

# My file size (bytes)
    my $logFileSize = -s $log_file;

# My file size (Mb)
    my $logFileSizeMB = $logFileSize / 1000000;

# File size limit
    my $fileSizeLimit = 100;

# Get Date
my $date = localtime->strftime('%m/%d/%Y');

# New File Name
my $newFileName = "testLog_$date.log";

sub main {

    if ($logFileSizeMB > $fileSizeLimit) {

        close $log_fh or die "Could not close file $log_file: $!";

        #print "$newFileName\n";
        rename("testLog.log", "testLog_$date.log") || die ("Error Renaming 
File");



        #open my $new_log_fh, '>', $new_log_file or die "Could not open file 
$new_log_file: $! +";
        #close $new_log_fh or die "Could not close file $new_log_file: $!";

        print "New log file created successfully!";

    } else {

        print "File size is under $fileSizeLimit";

    }


    exit(0);
}

main();
```

When I run this the file remains unchanged... any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Just the "Error Rename File at DeleteLogFile.pl line 58"

Comment: Fine, let me rephrase: What error did `rename` return? (Change `die ("Error Renaming 
File")` to `die("Error renaming \"testLog.log\" to \"testLog_$date.log\": $!\n")`)

Comment: Now I get "Error renaming "testLog.log" to "testLog_09/05/2017.log": No such file or directory" but the file is in the same folder as the script

Comment: Perl's `rename` simply calls the `rename` system call. The docs for the `rename` system call (`rename(2)`) say: *ENOENT: The link named by oldpath does not exist; or, **a directory component in newpath does not exist**; or, oldpath or newpath is an empty string.* There's no directory named `testLog_09` in the CWD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/` is not a valid character for file names since it's the directory separator. You effectively asked to rename `testLog.log` in the current dir to `2017.log` in the directory `testLog_09/05`. That directory doesn't exist.

Change

```
my $date = localtime->strftime('%m/%d/%Y');
```

to

```
my $date = localtime->strftime('%m-%d-%Y');
```

Better yet, use a format that sorts naturally.

```
my $date = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: That worked... How come the error was "No such file or directory"? If it was an issue with the new name format

Comment: You asked to rename the file to `2017.log` in the directory `testLog_09/05`. That directory doesn't exist.